# Exponential random variable

Tags: probability, random-variable

The time it takes a printer to print a job is an exponential random variable with mean of 10 seconds. You send a job to the printer at 9:00 am, and it appears to be the fourth in line. What is the probability that your job will be ready before 9:01 (i.e. before 60 seconds)

My solution:

$E[X] = 1/λ = 10$

$λ=1/10$

$P(X≥a) = e^{-λa}$

$P(X<60) = 1 - P(X≥60) = 1 - e^{-60/10} = 1 - e^{-6} = 1 -1/e^6 = 1 - 0.0024 = 0.9976$

Would the printer being "the fourth in line" would make a difference?

Comment: It's not the *printer* that's fourth in line. The 'it' refers to the preceding occurrence of 'job' rather 'printer'. Your print job has three others ahead of it on the printer, which will print before yours.

Comment: So how can I add that delay to the solution

Comment: You should know what the distribution of time for each job is. Do you know anything about the sum of such random variables?

Comment: No sir I don't, but what if we assign the mean of 10 seconds to each of them?

Comment: That's what the first sentence implies. But you need more than the mean. If you don't know that the sum of exponentials is gamma it's going to take you a while to work it out.

Comment: @Glen_b He could just look it up on wikipedia… :)

Answer (score 1):

To understand what is required, consider a slightly simpler problem: how much time does it take two jobs to finish? Call these jobs $X$ and $Y$, which are independent $Exp(1/10)$ random variables. What is the distribution of $T = X+Y$?

The pdf of an $Exp(1/10)$ r.v. is $f(x) = \frac{1}{10}e^{\frac{-x}{10}}$, which implies that if the value of $X$ was known, say $X=x$, then the pdf for $T = X+Y$ given $X=x$ would be $g(t) = \frac{1}{10}e^{\frac{-(t-x)}{10}}$, where $t$ must now be greater than $x$. That is the same as the original distribution only shifted $x$ seconds to the right.

Since we know the pdf for $X$ and the pdf for $T|X=x$, then we find the marginal distribution of $T$ by integrating/averaging over our uncertainty about $X$. In what follows, think of fixing $T$ at $t$ and taking a weighted average of the possible values of the conditional pdf $T|X=x$ where the weights are given by the pdf for $X$ over $0<x< t$:

$$\int_0^{t} \frac{1}{10}e^{\frac{-(t-x)}{10}} f(x) \;dx = \int_0^{t} \frac{1}{10^2}e^{\frac{-(t-x)}{10}}e^{\frac{-x}{10}}\;dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{10^2}e^{-t}\int_0^{t}\;dx$$
$$=\frac{1}{10^2}t\;e^{-\frac{t}{10}}$$

This pdf has the form of a gamma, namely $Gamma(2,1/10)$. It is not hard to see that if we iterate the procedure above to extend to the required four jobs, the power in the constant term and in the $t$ term will increment by 1 each time, so that the pdf will be $\frac{1}{10^4}t^3\;e^{-\frac{t}{10}}$, a $Gamma(4,1/10)$. Now you can integrate to find $P(t\le 60)$;